# continuity extension

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous for each $n$, and suppose that $f_n\rightrightarrows f$ on each closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that $f$ will be continuous on $[a,b]$, but how do I extend it to $\mathbb{R}$? A simple hint will be enough.

Comment: Choose a particular point in $\mathbb{R}$ call it $x$. Can you show that $f$ is continuous at $x$?

Comment: So my idea here is that we take the min $\delta$ On the complements of [a,b] and do the $\epsilon/3$ argument

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Continuity is a local property.

Comment: So my idea here is that we take the min $\delta$ On the complements of [a,b] and do the $\epsilon/3$ argument. This uses that the sequence fn is continuous on its restrictions

Comment: @Hawk: It's much simpler than that. You only need to verify continuity at each point $x\in\mathbb R$. Any point $x$ belongs to $[x-1,x+1]$, say. Hence, what do you know about $f$ restricted to the interval $[x-1,x+1]$? Hence, what do you know about the continuity of $f$ at $x$?

Comment: So basically we are saying the answer is staring at us. That is since I already know continuity on [a,b], it is cont at x in the set, so for each x this extends to any x on the line?

Comment: @Hawk: Yes, the answer is basically staring at us. Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[x-1,x+1]$, and the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, $f$ is continuous on $[x-1,x+1]$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Can you verify if my original sketch idea works? That is I take $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ on the compliments of [a,b]. Then set the uniform delta $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_{[a,b]}\}$and perform the epsilon 3 argument?

Comment: @Hawk: But the convergence isn't uniform on the complement of $[a,b]$ since the complement of $[a,b]$ is unbounded, so I don't see how you can get a uniform $\delta$ like you are proposing.

Comment: No sorry I meant the $\delta$ I have written works on the complement of [a,b] for the given$ \epsilon_{[a,b]}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85363/discussion-between-aortiz-and-hawk).